# Do @reply comments get deleted as well?

Tags: support, comments, replies

I was going back to look at a comment I posted to someone (as I wanted to remove it after he/she could see it), but I noticed that it is not in my comments/activity tab.

Remembering the post I added the @reply to, the original comment was deleted by the poster(I presume) and my comment is no longer there.

Do the @reply get removed if the original comment is deleted or removed? Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do the @reply get removed if the original comment is deleted or removed?

No. This is not possible.

What happened here—and I'm assuming you're talking about [this post](https://superuser.com/a/580122/48078)—is that the original comment and your reply were deleted by a moderator as they were too chatty and really not relevant.

Comment: Got it and makes sense.